# selenium grid showing max session 5 in config while setting up node is given max session =20

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

Selenium grid showing max session 5 in config.
while setting up node i have given max session = 20.
while checking with thread=22 also only 5 chrome  taking up rest are in queue.
please find attached.
please help to resolve issue.

code for node:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://ipaddress/grid/register -port portnumber -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=20,maxSession=20
```

Grid

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue and resolved it by using separate

> -maxSession 20

argument instead of specifying as part of the -browser argument.

EDIT - I'm also using selenium-server-standalone-3.1.4.0.jar and confirmed that the selenium grid shows the expected maxSession value in the node configuration.